# Role based permissions system

Tags: angular, angular8, canactivate

I've never done this before and couldn't find a good reference online so I'm asking.
I'm building angular web app and want to make a role -> permission system.
I've made `roleGuard` with `CanActivate`, but I cannot find a good way to make logic for checking permissions for it.
Storing permissions in token or `localstorage` and asking DB if I can access each resource seems kinda stupid. Is there concept that I could use that I haven't think of yet?

Comment: what is your logic for checking permissions ?

Comment: That's the problem, I thought of checking if requested module id in in permissions array as the most basic one. But storing permissions in localstorage don't seem like a good idea, sending them through jwt also doesn't sound good. Asking db for each and everyone sounds shitty too... And I don't know how to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `localStorage`/`sessionStorage` is definitely not a good idea.

I propose you to make a API call at the time of initialisation of your root component, store data in a variable of one of your service and use it in your `roleGuard`. With this approach you will not be using browser's storage and there will be only one API call at the initialisation of your app.

Even if the user refreshes the page at some point, the initialisation process will happen again, so just one API at all.